# Change text to indicate BUY or SELL from database

Tags: android, mysql

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
    Glide.with(context)
            .load("http://192.168.60.37/signalss/image/" + list_data.get(position).get("Icon"))
            .crossFade()
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(holder.imgsignals);
    holder.txtsignals1.setText(list_data.get(position).get("SignalsId"));
    holder.txtsignals2.setText(list_data.get(position).get("PairName"));
    holder.txtsignals3.setText(list_data.get(position).get("SignalsPosition"));
    holder.txtsignals4.setText(list_data.get(position).get("AreaOpenPrice1"));
    holder.txtsignals5.setText(list_data.get(position).get("AreaOpenPrice2"));
    holder.txtsignals6.setText(list_data.get(position).get("StopLoss"));
    holder.txtsignals7.setText(list_data.get(position).get("TargetProfit1"));
    holder.txtsignals8.setText(list_data.get(position).get("TargetProfit3"));
    holder.txtsignals9.setText(list_data.get(position).get("AddDate"));
}
```

I want to change this to BUY or SELL.

My db:
[image: Mydb]

My android:
[image: myandroid]

I thought to use `ifelse`, but how?

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: Sorry for the tag ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setText as below:     `holder.txtsignals1.setText((list_data.get(position).get("SignalsId").equals("B") ? "BUY" : "SELL");`